# Arduino problem with uploading program to Arduino Uno WiFi through USB

Tags: usb, permissions, arduino

I have problem with uploading Arduino program to my Arduino Uno Wifi device through USB interface on my Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS. After initiating upload process I get this error:

> avrdude: ser_open(): can't open device "/dev/ttyUSB0": Permission denied

I already tried to solve this problem by common ways like changing user permissions on this interface and adding logged user to *dialout* group with these commands:

```
sudo usermod -a -G dialout cmaa
sudo chmod a+rw /dev/ttyUSB0
```

None of these commands solved my problem and error message from Arduino IDE remains the same. Do you have any suggestions how to solve this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Already tried restarting the system.

Comment: I installed it through Ubuntu Software center.

Comment: Thank you very much. Answer from the link you given really solved my problem.

Comment: In that case I'm marking your question as duplicate. ;-)